# SSH from one server to another

Tags: networking, ssh

I have 2 servers, named A and B.

I can connect to servers A and B directly from my PC through SSH. I logged into server A, and when I tried to SSH into server B from there, it does not respond.

What may be the cause?

Here's what I did to try to connect from A to B:

```
$ ssh -v user@190.xx.xx.xx  
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 190.xx.xx.xx [190.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
```

and it strucks over here.

These two servers are virtual & are from the same data center and there ip are very close.
They are connecting when i tried to connect from other servers.

Comment: I didn't  got any warning message.

Comment: Looks like the problem might actually be on a lower networking layer and unrelated to SSH. Can you `ping <B>` from A (replace `<B>` with its host name or IP address)? If yes, can you establish a raw TCP connection to port 22 with `telnet <B> 22`?

Comment: ping is blocked and telnet struck at trying.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't ping B from A you have a networking issue unrelated to SSH that you need to resolve first. Verify that there are no firewall rules ion place that block the traffic and contact the hosting company about the issue.

If you need help with that or have any other follow-up questions please [open a new question](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

on serv B

- edit file /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add :
   
  SyslogFacility AUTH 
  LogLevel ERROR
- save and quit the file.
- Run the following command (1): `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

After that, from server A, try to SSH into server B, and send back the return of (1).

on server A :

- open a terminal : telnet @IP 22
  change @IP with the ip adresse of server B.

and  send the response

Comment: there is no auth.log. only dmesg, messages and secure are in /var/log

Comment: # Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
LogLevel ERROR

Comment: telnet struck at trying